# C++ Boost - Breadth First Search using Compressed Sparse Row Graph

Tags: c++, boost, sparse-matrix, breadth-first-search

I am trying to write the logic for breadth-first search. I was easily able to access all the neighboring nodes for a vertex using the `boost::adjacent_vertices(start_node, graph)` for the `boost::adjacency_list` format, but I am facing issues with the `boost::compressed_sparse_row_graph` format.

My specific question is how do I get all the neighboring (adjacent) nodes for a given node so that I can then put them in a queue and continue with the BFS loop given that my graph is stored in the CSR format as mentioned above. I cannot seem to figure our how to iterate over the adjacent nodes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

### Obtaining adjacent vertices

Obtaining the adjacent vertices for a `boost::compressed_sparse_row_graph` should not differ from other `boost` graph types. You should be able to obtain the adjacent vertices with `boost::adjacent_vertices`:

```cpp
using AdjacencyIterator = Graph::adjacency_iterator;

AdjacencyIterator neighbor{};
AdjacencyIterator end{};

for (boost::tie(neighbor, end) = boost::adjacent_vertices(current, graph);
    neighbor != end; ++neighbor) {
  // ...
}
```

If you can use [structured bindings](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding) (C++17), this can be simplified to:

```cpp
for (auto [neighbor, end] = boost::adjacent_vertices(current, graph);
    neighbor != end; ++neighbor) {
  // ...
}
```

### Implementing BFS manually

If you want to implement BFS manually (instead of using `boost::breadth_first_search`), this could be done as follows:

```cpp
#include <boost/graph/compressed_sparse_row_graph.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <queue>

using Graph = boost::compressed_sparse_row_graph<>;
using Vertex = Graph::vertex_descriptor;

int main() {
  size_t vertices = 6;
  std::vector<std::pair<Vertex, Vertex>> edges{
      {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}, {1, 0}, {1, 3}, {1, 5}, {2, 0},
      {2, 5}, {3, 1}, {3, 4}, {4, 1}, {5, 0}, {5, 2}};

  Graph graph{boost::edges_are_sorted, edges.begin(), edges.end(), vertices};

  Vertex start = 0;

  auto indices = boost::get(boost::vertex_index, graph);
  auto visited = boost::make_vector_property_map<bool>(indices);

  std::queue<Vertex> queue{};

  queue.push(start);
  visited[start] = true;

  while (!queue.empty()) {
    Vertex current{queue.front()};
    queue.pop();

    std::cout << "Current: " << current << std::endl;

    for (auto [neighbor, end] = boost::adjacent_vertices(current, graph);
         neighbor != end; ++neighbor) {

      if (visited[*neighbor]) {
        continue;
      }

      queue.push(*neighbor);
      visited[*neighbor] = true;
    }
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

### Using `boost::breadth_first_search`

If you do not want to implement BFS manually, you can use `boost::breadth_first_search` instead:

```cpp
#include <boost/graph/breadth_first_search.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/compressed_sparse_row_graph.hpp>

#include <iostream>

using Graph = boost::compressed_sparse_row_graph<>;
using Vertex = Graph::vertex_descriptor;

struct Visitor : public boost::default_bfs_visitor {
  void discover_vertex(Vertex v, const Graph &) const {
    std::cout << "Current: " << v << std::endl;
  }
};

int main() {
  size_t vertices = 6;
  std::vector<std::pair<Vertex, Vertex>> edges{
      {0, 1}, {0, 2}, {0, 3}, {1, 0}, {1, 3}, {1, 5}, {2, 0},
      {2, 5}, {3, 1}, {3, 4}, {4, 1}, {5, 0}, {5, 2}};

  Graph graph{boost::edges_are_sorted, edges.begin(), edges.end(), vertices};

  Vertex start = 0;
  Visitor visitor{};

  boost::breadth_first_search(graph, start, boost::visitor(visitor));

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```